# How do I use git svn to clone more than one branch, but not all?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

Cloning an entire svn repo is simple: `git svn clone svn://somesvnrepo --std-layout (or use --branches=/branches)`.

Cloning a single branch is also simple, `git svn clone svn://somesvnrepo/branches/mybranch`

But how can I *git svn clone* multiple specific branches? Say I wanted to grab `/branches/red`, `/branches/green` and `/branches/blue`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766226/7976758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following command and add all branches where you want to clone:

```
git svn clone -s --prefix=svn/ -b branches -b branches/red -b branches/green -b branches/blue
```