# Clone Subversion branches to Git

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to clone part of a very old Subversion repo (started 15 years ago).

This is the layout:

[image]

I would like to import all folders from `Users` as branches to Git, with history.

Tried the following:

[git svn clone specific branches and merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746949/git-svn-clone-specific-branches-and-merge/50766226#50766226)

But I get the following:

[image]

Branches are not imported.

**UPDATE**

Is there a way to detect branches?

Not all branches are directly below Users, some have more folders hierarchy.

Comment: Try `git svn clone -b Users`

Comment: this will import all the folders inside as branches?

Comment: Yep, that's the point of [`--branches/--tags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt--bltbranchessubdirgt). They name parent directories which subdirectories are branches/tags.

Comment: please see my edit above

Comment: Nop, AFAIK Subversion really has neither branches nor tags — everything is a directory.